# Displaying JSON webapi element in HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm currently struggling to display results from a Web API, I'm new to this kind of thing, so forgive the horrible understanding. My error is down to authentication. I have since discovered that the API link was incorrect, and now (via python) I can use to call the correct results. My issue lies in not knowing how to get the same results in Javascript, and parsing it down to only display the string "value". I will post below a sample of the data coming through from the API and will highlight exactly what I need. The overall aim is to display the "value" number in a P tag, the location of which can be found in my HTML. Here is my the section of html in which I'm trying to display the value in:

```
<div class="card-content">
    <p>The light sensor will detect exterior lighting conditions, and will turn on or off any outside lights based on the enviroment.</p><br>
    <center>
        <div class="reading-circle light" id="tempcircle">
            <!----VALUE HERE IN P ELEMENT---->
        </div>
    </center>
</div>
```

And here is my JS file;

```
const app = document.getElementById('tempcircle');

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://swagger.richard-murphy.iotpdev.com/api/1/devices/snapshot/paged', true);
request.onload = function () {

var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        data.forEach(sensor => {
            const t_reading = document.createElement('p');
            sensor.value = sensor.value.substring(0, 300);
            p.textContent = `${sensor.value}`;
            tempcircle.appendChild(p);
        });
    }
}
request.send();
```

API Sample

```
{
    "id": "e370df3d-6283-459f-9d8e-0b614dec578b",
    "name": "Themometer",
    "typeId": "88f06b08-59e0-43ae-ae95-2d4ee4f1a66e",
    "deviceId": "fb903ae2-67de-46cb-8cb7-9eb3faf62e1d",
    "attributes": {},
    "minimumNormalOperatingValue": -15,
    "maximumNormalOperatingValue": 60,
    "minimumValue": 0,
    "maximumValue": 40,
    "displayName": "Thermometer"
  },
```

The above sample does not include the value attribute as the device is not recording any results, but when we run it through python we are giving it dummy values as it will eventually come from a live sensor

Comment: May we know what is not working with your code?

Comment: "struggling" isn't an error message or problem statement. Have you got some console error? Unexpected behaviour? Have you debugged your code? Just out of curiosity I tried to open the URL in your example manually in a browser, but it a) tried to redirect me to a login page, and then b) the login page timed out and gave a gateway error. So even if there wasn't a timeout problem, it looks like the URL requires the client to authenticate to it, and from what I can see your AJAX request is not sending any kind of credentials (i.e. username/password, API key, access token or whatever is needed)

Comment: Failed to load https://richard-murphy.iotpdev.com/api/1/devices/snapshot/paged: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. - This was the chrome console error. I had to remove the swagger from the link for it to work (ish). Authorisation is an issue, but I'm unsure how to add the login details etc.

Comment: I have edited the post to be more in depth. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think there is an error in your js.  It looks like the code  
`const t_reading = document.createElement('p');
            sensor.value = sensor.value.substring(0, 300);
            p.textContent = `${sensor.value}`;
            tempcircle.appendChild(p);` 
should be this `const t_reading = document.createElement('p');
            sensor.value = sensor.value.substring(0, 300);
            t_reading.textContent = `${sensor.value}`;
            app.appendChild(t_reading);`